# How can I delete a local video file after selecting from a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, I have the user select a video from their library using a UIImagePickerController. After they edit and choose it, it plays inside a UIView for them to preview before uploading it. My problem is that after the user uploads the video, I believe that the video is still stored on the apps storage. I want to remove it from the app storage after it is uploaded to a database. Is there a way to delete the videoURL or AVAsset after it's use.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL
    video = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: video)
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = uploadButton.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.masksToBounds = true
    uploadButton.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    uploadButton.isEnabled = false
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        self.player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        self.player.play()
    }
    player.play()

    let uButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Upload", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleUpload))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = uButton
    newVideoURL = videoURL
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Not entirely sure if the video is saved on the app storage but I noticed it takes up more and more space after each video I upload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if someone else had this issue and if you have a solution for it?